# Android notification does not light up screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating an android app using notifications.

My problem is that when one comes in while the screen is turned off it won't turn on.

**This is my notification channel:**

```
    val channel = NotificationChannel(
    getString(R.string.notification_channel),
    "Notification Channel",
    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
    channel.enableVibration(true)
    channel.apply { description = "Reminders" }
```

**This is my alarm manager:**

```
val pendingIntent =
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationRequestCode, intent, 0)

val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    notificationMillis,
    pendingIntent
)
```

**My intent works with a broadcast receiver from where the notification is created.
This is it:**

```
val notification =
        Notification.Builder(
            callingContext,
            callingContext.getString(R.string.notification_channel)
        ).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.access_time_24px)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle).setContentText(notificationText)
            .setStyle(Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationText))
            .setContentIntent(notificationClickPendingIntent)
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(callingContext)) {
        notify(currentChannel, notification.build())
    }
```

I haven't found any documentation explicitly describing how to handle this.
RTC_WAKEUP, high priority and allowWhileIdle all don't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Notifications by themselves do not turn on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is java, but the usage of `PowerManager` is the important part:

```
createNotification(); //your implementation
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 20 ? pm.isInteractive() : pm.isScreenOn(); // check if screen is on
if (!isScreenOn) {
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "myApp:notificationLock");
    wl.acquire(3000); //set your time in milliseconds
}
```